# clocktable or agenda view showing single clock-in/out entries ordered by clock-in time

Tags: org-agenda, org-clock

I don't really have a strict agenda, so I clock-in/out of my tasks as I need to.

I would like to see a list of this clocked times in an agenda view, but I need to see them ordered by the clock-in time, and I don't want just the sum.

What I hope to achieve is to see if there are "holes" in my day, where I did not clock anything.

E.g., given the following org file

```
# mwe.org
* aaa
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2024-02-16 Fri 14:20]--[2024-02-16 Fri 14:30] =>  0:10
CLOCK: [2024-02-16 Fri 14:00]--[2024-02-16 Fri 14:10] =>  0:10
:END:
* bbb
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2024-02-16 Fri 14:10]--[2024-02-16 Fri 14:20] =>  0:10
:END:
```

I would like some display like the following:

```
Friday     16 February 2024
               8:00 ┄┄┄┄┄ ┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
              10:00 ┄┄┄┄┄ ┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
              12:00 ┄┄┄┄┄ ┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
  mwe:        14:00 ┄┄┄┄┄ aaa
              14:10 ┄┄┄┄┄ bbb
              14:20 ┄┄┄┄┄ aaa
              16:00 ┄┄┄┄┄ ┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
              18:00 ┄┄┄┄┄ ┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
              20:00 ┄┄┄┄┄ ┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
```

I tried with [`org-timeline`](https://github.com/Fuco1/org-timeline) but wasn't lucky